Undefined reference errors when cross-compiling using target device (armhf) sysroot libraries on x86_64 host
Host Device:
Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC 11.4.0 (PPA upgrade)
Target Device:
Zynq, Ubuntu 18.04 with GCC 11.4.0 (PPA upgrade)
Cross-Compilation Toolchain:
ARM GNU Toolchain 11.3.0 from the official ARM website
Issue:
I encountered the following errors when compiling certain source files:
    /opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_join', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'hypot', version 'GLIBC_2.35'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'stat64', version 'GLIBC_2.33'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'exp', version 'GLIBC_2.29'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_setspecific', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to '__libc_single_threaded', version 'GLIBC_2.32'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'log', version 'GLIBC_2.29'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_rdlock', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_create', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_once', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_key_delete', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_getspecific', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pow', version 'GLIBC_2.29'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_wrlock', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_rwlock_unlock', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_detach', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_key_create', version 'GLIBC_2.34'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'lstat64', version 'GLIBC_2.33'
/opt/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libstdc++.so: error: undefined reference to 'fstat64', version 'GLIBC_2.33'

he error messages indicate that the libstdc++.so used by the toolchain cannot find certain function definitions, and it seems like there might be a glibc mismatch. Upon checking, I found that the toolchain supports up to GLIBCXX_3.4.29, with the final linked version being libstdc++.so.6.0.29. However, the sysroot libraries from my target device support up to GLIBCXX_3.4.32, with the final linked version being libstdc++.so.6.0.32. The difference seems minor, so I wouldn't expect these errors to occur.
Additionally, I tried using the 12.2 version of the toolchain, which links to libstdc++.so.6.0.32, but the same errors still persist.
How should I resolve this issue?

18.04 reached end of standard support April, 2023, and is off-topic here. Backup your files and upgradeor reinstall to 22.04 or 24.04 (see previous answers for upgrading an EOL release.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.
